# Linq Foreach skipping line

Tags: c#, regex, linq, foreach

I have this linq foreach

```
        public Func<List<string>, Foobar, List<string>> ExtractClassName = (lines, foo)
        =>
        {
            temp = lines.FindAll(_FooRege.IsMatch);
            temp.ForEach(t => { lines.Remove(t); });

            lines.ForEach(
                lin =>
                {
                    if (foo.FooRege.IsMatch(lin))
                    {
                        docsText.AppendLine(TrimSlashes(lin));
                        lines.Remove(lin);
                    }
                    else if(_FooRege.IsMatch(lin))
                    {
                        _foo.ClassName = lin.Split(' ').Last();
                        lines.Remove(lin);
                    }
                });
            return lines;
        };
```

TestData

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary <- skips this one
/// </summary>
```

After he hits the first match in the first if everything is okay, but then the second hit of the first if a line is skipped.. Have no clue why that is happening.

Comment: What line is skipped? Give more precise description to your problem including test data and desired outcome

Comment: What do you mean a line is skipped? Is there a string that is not displayed? Or is a carriage return displayed causing a break in the display? If you could provide sample input and output, that would help out.

Comment: Aha ok , i'm playing around with regexs and i'm using a code file to pratice on hang on ill change the topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never ever modify a collection which you are currently iterating over. Create a copy of the collection first, in your case the following small change will do it:

```
foo.ToList().ForEach(...
```